# Sonar maven builds are falling

Tags: php, maven, utf-8, sonarqube

When I try to run `mvn sonar:sonar -e` in projects root dir build is falling with error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Unable to read and import the source file : '/www/hudson/proj_beta/source/bin/report.php' with the charset : 'UTF-8'.
org.sonar.api.resources.File@10ade81[key=bin/report.php,dir=bin,filename=report.php,language=PHP]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:103)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:79)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to read and import the source file : '/www/hudson/c2c_beta/source/bin/report.php' with the charset : 'UTF-8'.
        at org.sonar.api.batch.AbstractSourceImporter.parseDirs(AbstractSourceImporter.java:84)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.AbstractSourceImporter.analyse(AbstractSourceImporter.java:69)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.AbstractSourceImporter.analyse(AbstractSourceImporter.java:60)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:64)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:93)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:143)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:111)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:101)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:102)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:100)
        at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.executeBatch(SonarMojo.java:152)
        at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:142)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:98)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.resources.DuplicatedSourceException: org.sonar.api.resources.File@10ade81[key=bin/report.php,dir=bin,filename=report.php,language=PHP]
        at org.sonar.batch.index.SourcePersister.saveSource(SourcePersister.java:45)
        at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultPersistenceManager.setSource(DefaultPersistenceManager.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.index.DefaultIndex.setSource(DefaultIndex.java:402)
        at org.sonar.batch.DefaultSensorContext.saveSource(DefaultSensorContext.java:159)
        at org.sonar.api.batch.AbstractSourceImporter.parseDirs(AbstractSourceImporter.java:81)
        ... 37 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 23 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 08 14:50:49 EET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/42M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It started to fall after unit-test were added to source dir.
Google search didn't give any clue.

The file is in utf-8:
    report.php: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Any suggestions?

Comment: I reckon the file contains non UTF-8 encoded characters. Tricky problem to diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an [open issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1238) with Sonar, caused due to the same php file name in say, source and test folders.   The issue exists for [java as well](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2444?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab). According to [this](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3024), this should be fixed in the next release.

Possible Workaround:

- If you encounter this problem, you can try to rename (if possible)
  the test files that make the analysis fail

Comment: Thanks. I have renamed report.php file in tests and it's OK now, bu the the other file in tests is now causing error: IndexControllerTest.php in tests and there is no such file in the main code.
The error backtrace is exactly the same. 
What could be this time?

Comment: Maybe its because my tests are in the same directory?
main code is in source/ and tests are in source/tests/

Answer (score 0):

First, are all your sources encoded in UTF-8? 
If so, have you tried removing the report.php source file, just to see if it's not only this class that has a problem?